# Autodesk Forge - Get Access Token with cURL and cmd prompt

Tags: curl, cmd, oauth, token, autodesk-forge

i've started recently with Autodesk Forge but i'm stuck at the procedure to obtain a two-legged access token by using cURL and the command prompt. After having installed cURL, this is the text i've written in the cmd prompt window:

[image]

(I've copied it from the Autodesk Forge Tutorial).

This is the image of the bad response:

[image]

What am i missin? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you check your single quotes? looks like some characters are not used correctly. I just tried my side, looks good as you can see from the picture.[image]

Btw, since you are not familiar with Curl, I would suggest you to use another tool named **Postman**, you can download it https://www.postman.com/downloads/ if you are interested, it's pretty convenient to use, and we provided many collection to help you easily try with Forge APIs, check at https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/my-postman-collection, or search ***Postman*** within samples at https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge

Comment: I've tried replacing the single quotes with double quotes but it gave me a similar error. Probably because i'm using Windows instead of Mac? Anyway, in the meanwhile i've started using Postman and the collection created for the Design Automation API for Revit tutorial: it's fantastic!! Thank you very much for your help!!